# Trigonometry, complex numbers

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Does $\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)*\cos(b)-\sin(a)*\sin(b)$
 apply even for complex values.
If so why?

Comment: Do you know about the relation between the (real) trigonometric functions and the (complex) exponential function?

Answer (score 1):

For a complex number $z$, sine and cosine defined by
$$\cos z=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}\quad\text{and} \quad \sin z=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$$
therefore you can compute
$$\cos(a+b)=\frac{e^{i(a+b)}+e^{-i(a+b)}}{2}$$
and proceed.

---

Edit: From Euler formula $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$, we have
$$\cos x=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}\quad\text{and} \quad \sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$
for real $x$.

Therefore it leads us to define sine  and cosine of a complex variable in that form. Also the Taylor series
$$e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$$
makes this definition firm.

Comment: why is it so?Is there a proof why cos z=e^iz+e^-iz/2\

Comment: i do know e^i x=cos x+i sin x then why is it extended for complex values?

Comment: @ArvindPuthucode This formula for $e^{ix}$ holds for any $x\in\mathbb{C}$ because the series expansions of each expression converge for all $x\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @ArvindPuthucode Check the edit please.

Comment: oh thanks man .

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider a number $a+ib$.

Then

$\cos(a+ib) = \cos a \cos(ib) - \sin a \sin(ib) = \color{blue}{\cos a \cosh b - i \sin a \sinh b}$

as $\cos(ix) = \cosh x$ and $\sin(ix) = i\sinh x$